# Нижний элемент в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте! Имеется ListView, который занимает в высоту только верхнюю половину экрана, в связи с этим нижний элемент в ListView обрезается при прокручивании списка. Как наиболее простым способом сделать так, чтобы нижний элемент либо показывался полностью/не показывался вообще, или сделать небольшой градиент в прозрачность у последнего элемента, чтобы эта граница не была так резко посреди экрана?

P.S. Элементы списка появляются с анимацией

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод

```
listView.getLastVisiblePosition()
```

и при скроллировании ListView скрывать последний видимый элемент.

Также можно взглянуть на RecyclerView, где есть возможность показать последний полностью видимый элемент:

```
linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
```

Comment: Согласен, `RecyclerView` во многом проще чем `ListView` :)